# C# Code to Abstract Syntax Tree in Java

Tags: c#, java, abstract-syntax-tree, pmd

Currently I'm working with my team on a project for school. This project is about building a static analysis tool to review programming projects. We've build the Java part with the use of PMD. We use PMD to create a Abstract Syntax Tree for the Java code we put in there.

Now we need to do the same for C#, but we couldn't find a tool that is written in Java which creates an Abstract Syntax Tree out of our C# code. Thus my question is: Does anyone know any type of opensource tool that is able to do this for us?

If the answer is no; does anyone know how we can achieve this in a different way?

Comment: Try [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org), written in Java but can output C# code.

Comment: Do note that there is a C# grammar available for download on the page @SilentSojourner links.  [Direct Link](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1335792765749/CSharp_4.0_grammar.zip)